# PHP Show .m3u8 Live Stream

Tags: php, header

I build a live streaming website. The .m3u8 and .ts files are stored in server. I want to hide these files. I made a password protect page, if the user logged in, open this .php file will do the same thing as open .m3u8 file.

```
$reqpath = 'test/test.m3u8';
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache,must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0",false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-type:application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($reqpath));
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($reqpath));
@readfile($reqpath);
```

When I logged in and open this php file on safari, nothing happened... It does not show the video. Can anyone help me?

 Or do you have other solutions to protect .m3u8?
Thanks

Comment: could you specify nothing?

Comment: Just a black page and a play button in the middle of it. The play button automatically goes to the top of the page and then disappear... It cannot be clicked.

Comment: The `Content-Disposition` header is for downloading a file. if you just want to display the stream i don't think that is what you want.

Comment: The Content type should be `application/x-mpegURL` or `vnd.apple.mpegURL`

Comment: I removed "Content-Disposition" and changed the content type, same thing happens... Play button automatically goes up and cannot be clicked.

Comment: I know safari/ios to little to know what is going on. But if you want to support multible browsers for your hls stream you need an hls player anyway. eg https://github.com/clappr/clappr

Comment: Yeah, I am using video.js and it can play on chrome, firefox, edge. I just do not want them to find the real .m3u8 url from the source code. Or, they can find the real url, but they must login first and then they can view .m3u8.

Comment: soooo. you don't open the m3u8 in the browser directly but instead a html site that uses video.js.... In this case i would check for errors in the developer tools and check in the network tab if the content is what you expect. (I could also imagine problems with relative paths in the m3u8 file as you now serve it from a different directory then the original file maybe?)

Comment: They are all right. I guess I will try to find another solution like password protect...

Comment: What error do you get in the developer tools?

Comment: In your example code you use `$reqpath = 'test/test.m3u8';` if your m3u8 file contains relative paths they are relative to `./test/`. now you serve the file from a different location (i assume, its hard to guess, it would be nice if you could give more information :) ) and now the relative paths are relative to `./` so the .ts files can't be found anymore.